# How to open a .bat in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, button, windows-forms-designer

I am doing a program and want to open the .bat file with the help of a button. I also found a code but when I send the program to my friend the .bat file does not open because I wrote my path. Is there a possibility that I can add a bat in the program and that the bat opens on every pc?

I tried a lot of codes but no on can help me

Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c C:\name.bat");

.

Comment: Hello, the code dont work do you know a other way

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [current path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) of your application at run time like this:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

And then you can concatenate to it your file name.
This will make sure that anytime you run the application it will get the right path and pass it to cmd.

Also try to test it by copying your application to different directories in your machine before sending it to your friend, just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

here the code and explain

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = null;
            try
            {
                string batDir = string.Format(@"D:\"); //path of bat
                proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "testbat.bat";
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                MessageBox.Show("Bat file executed !!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, i tried the code but i dont work it opens on by pc but not on my friends one. Do you know how to make it so it can runs on my friends pc.

Comment: pls answer i need it really :)

Comment: what is Friend's computer running os?

Comment: My Friend has Windows

Comment: try the duplicate question answer